# Tuple function in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples, higher-order-functions

I have the function

```
getCode :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
getCode = concatMap (uncurry replicate)`
```

I expect

```
getCode [(‘a’,4),(‘b’,1),(‘a’,3),(‘b’,1)]
```

to output

```
“aaaabaaab”
```

Instead I get an error that it does not match with the expected data type `[(a,Int)]`, and the actual data type is `[(Int,a)]`. How do i change it to make it work? Or any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the parameters of `replicate` with the [`flip`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) function:

> ```
> flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
> ```
>
> `flip f` takes its (first) two arguments in the reverse order of `f`.

```
getCode :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
getCode = concatMap (uncurry (flip replicate))
```

---

Or use [`swap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html#v:swap) from `Data.Tuple` to do the same thing with a tuple instead of function parameters:

```
getCode :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
getCode = concatMap (uncurry replicate . swap)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I was thinking of `reverse` function.

Comment: @BCKN `reverse` is for lists, but `swap` would work for tuples. Thanks for the memory jog ;)